# How to solve includePath error in VSCode in macos

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

Ever since my MacBook was updated, I am not able to solve this error that says "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath".
Here is my c_cpp_properties.json file.

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/g++",
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-apple-darwin20"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/g++",
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}
Try this path